# appcelerator ERROR | Hyperloop is unavailable in your plan

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have this error when compiling

2016-11-16T23:57:25.931Z | TRACE  | session already loaded in opts.session
2016-11-16T23:57:25.967Z | ERROR  | Hyperloop is unavailable in your plan.

Comment: Please give some more context regarding this error and what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have a Pro level subscription plan hyperloop is unavailable to you. Since your error states it is not included in your plan, I assume you do not. So, You would need to uncheck hyperloop in your TiApp.xml file. If you do have a pro, or higher I would try appc logout then appc login from terminal and try to clean and build again. If that fails I would contact support.